# Node-sass error during installation of node modules

Tags: linux, debian, node.js, npm

I'm trying to install Laravel on my Debian server, but it fails during installation of `node-sass`. I have had this setup for a long time and never experienced issues before. Maybe `node-sass` or `npm` changed something recently?

Hope you can help me, I have been stuck for 2 days now.

```
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.14
npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.3.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! node-sass@3.8.0 install: `node scripts/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@3.8.0 install script 'node scripts/install.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the node-sass package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node scripts/install.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs node-sass
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-sass
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution is

```
 npm install --no-optional
```

Comment: What does this flag do and why does it solve the issue?

Comment: This did not work for me node-sass@4.11.0